# MacBook Air crashes after lid close

Tags: sleep-wake, kernel-panic

I've been noticing that my MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015) restarts after I open the lid sometimes, indicating that it has crashed while asleep - can anyone decipher the attached error report and maybe give me some insight into what's going on?

Thank you!

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800fa279d7): "com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderInterfaceNub::setPowerState(0xffffff802016df00 : 0xffffff7f92e60f86, 2 -> 0) timed out after 30725 ms"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-6153.41.3/iokit/Kernel/IOServicePM.cpp:5302
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff90d46f3b40 : 0xffffff800f339a3b 
0xffffff90d46f3b90 : 0xffffff800f470fe5 
0xffffff90d46f3bd0 : 0xffffff800f462a5e 
0xffffff90d46f3c20 : 0xffffff800f2e0a40 
0xffffff90d46f3c40 : 0xffffff800f339127 
0xffffff90d46f3d40 : 0xffffff800f33950b 
0xffffff90d46f3d90 : 0xffffff800fad17f9 
0xffffff90d46f3e00 : 0xffffff800fa279d7 
0xffffff90d46f3e50 : 0xffffff800fa27599 
0xffffff90d46f3e60 : 0xffffff800fa3e94e 
0xffffff90d46f3ea0 : 0xffffff800fa26348 
0xffffff90d46f3ec0 : 0xffffff800f37b625 
0xffffff90d46f3f40 : 0xffffff800f37b151 
0xffffff90d46f3fa0 : 0xffffff800f2e013e 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19B88

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Thu Oct 17 16:17:15 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.41.3~29/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 7503CD47-851F-321E-8747-50DB4299165F
Kernel slide:     0x000000000f000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800f200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800f100000
System model name: MacBookAir7,2 (Mac-937CB26E2E02BB01)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 118366129931491
last loaded kext at 118330093306554: |SCSITaskUserClient    422.0.2 (addr 0xffffff7f92e69000, size 36864)
last unloaded kext at 117308888791536: >usb.cdc 5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f92dbf000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
com.avast.PacketForwarder   2.1
com.avast.FileShield    4.0.0
|SCSITaskUserClient 422.0.2
>!UCardReader   489.41.1
>!U!SCoexistentDriver   489.41.1
@filesystems.msdosfs    1.10
@fileutil   20.036.15
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>AGPM   111.2.5
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@filesystems.ntfs   3.14.3
>!AHDA  283.14
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 4.5.9
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   4.5.9
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.1f1
>pmtelemetry    1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!ABacklight    180.1
>!A!IBDWGraphics    14.0.2
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.3
>eficheck   1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!ALPC  3.1
>!AMCCSControl  1.13
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!ACameraInterface  7.6.0
>!A!IBDWGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.2
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.9
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3410.1
@filesystems.apfs   1412.41.1
>!AAHCIPort 341.0.2
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!UAudio    320.49
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
|IOUSBMass!SClass   4.0.4
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.14
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>!AGraphicsControl  4.5.9
|IOAVB!F    800.17
>!ASSE  1.0
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  4.5.9
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
|IONDRVSupport  568
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    4.5.9
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.2.7
>!AHDA!C    283.14
|IOGraphics!F   568
|IOHDA!F    283.14
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    810.1
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.1f1
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.1f1
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.1f1
>usb.!UHub  1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.6
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AHS!BDriver   3410.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.1f1
|IO!B!F 7.0.1f1
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.1f1
>!AMultitouchDriver 3410.2
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3410.1
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHSSPIHIDDriver   58
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.40.3
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.3
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.3
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.2
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.0
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.4.6
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>!AHSSPISupport 58
>!A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.41.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.40.7
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOTimeSync!F   810.1
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Comment: What version of macOS?  Do you have anything connected to USB or card reader?  There are lots of other reports of *com_apple_driver_AppleUSBCardReaderInterfaceNub* causing issues in Catalina - for example [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250721653?page=2) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250816333)

Comment: Catalina, 10.15.1. Thanks for those links, I'll look into them. And yes, I keep a JetDrive Lite in my SD card reader at all times - although it has never caused problems in the past.